# How can I get the id of the workflow instance in workflow form?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-webscripts

I have the FreeMarker template, which is the custom field for display some data about the business process.

Let's say, `userdetails.ftl`:

```
<@link href="${url.context}/res/components/workflow/workflow-form.css" group="workflow"/>
<#include "/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/common/utils.inc.ftl" />

<div class="form-field">
   <div id="...">
      <table id="..." class="yui-dt">
         <tr>
            <th class="yui-dt-liner">Field_1</th>
            <th class="yui-dt-liner">Field_2</th>
            <th class="yui-dt-liner">Field_3</th>
            <th class="yui-dt-liner">Field_4</th>
            ...
            <th class="yui-dt-liner">Field_N</th>
         </tr>
         ...
      </table>
   </div>
</div>

<script>

// Here I want to call REST back-end and parse the JSON response

</script>
```

Relevant part of the `share-config-custom.xml`:

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="mswf:reviewTask">
  <forms>
     <form>
        <field-visibility>
           <show id="mswf:userDetails" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
           <set id="userDetails" appearance="title" label="User Details" />
            <field id="mswf:userDetails" set="userDetails" label="User Details">
                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/userdetails.ftl" />
            </field>
           <field id="transitions" set="response" />
        </appearance>
     </form>
  </forms>
</config>
```

This template contains a table in which I would like to display the list of users who will participate in the business process (who was assigned).

Inside tags  `<script></script>` I want to invoke an embedded Alfresco WebScript (or my own - it's not important in this case) which returns me all the necessary information about the business process:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/workflow/versions/1/processes/26205/variables
```

,where `26205 == id` of the process instance.

I get the following:

```
{
   "list":{
      "pagination":{
         "count":36,
         "hasMoreItems":false,
         "totalItems":36,
         "skipCount":0,
         "maxItems":100
      },
      "entries":[
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_packageActionGroup",
               "type":"d:text"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_approveCount",
               "type":"d:double",
               "value":0.0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_reassignable",
               "type":"d:boolean",
               "value":true
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_priority",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":2
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"initiator",
               "type":"d:noderef",
               "value":"admin"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_actualRejectPercent",
               "type":"d:double",
               "value":0.0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_percentComplete",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_sendEMailNotifications",
               "type":"d:boolean",
               "value":false
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_reviewOutcome",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"Reject"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_workflowPriority",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":1
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_hiddenTransitions",
               "type":"d:text"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"workflowinstanceid",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"activiti$26205"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"taskFormKey",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"mswf:activitiReviewTask"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_workflowDueDate",
               "type":"d:date",
               "value":"2017-03-12T20:00:00.000+0000"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_requiredPercent",
               "type":"d:double",
               "value":100.0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_reviewerCount",
               "type":"d:double",
               "value":2.0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_package",
               "type":"bpm:workflowPackage",
               "value":"workspace://SpacesStore/72086323-6c65-46f9-a1ad-8877630a6b40"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_actualPercent",
               "type":"d:double",
               "value":0.0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"nrOfActiveInstances",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":2
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_workflowDescription",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"message..."
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_rejectCount",
               "type":"d:double",
               "value":0.0
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_packageItemActionGroup",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"edit_package_item_actions"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"companyhome",
               "type":"d:noderef",
               "value":"workspace://SpacesStore/64f9f3c3-9227-425d-b336-bd255ab94c83"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"_startTaskCompleted",
               "type":"d:datetime",
               "value":"2017-03-13T07:03:12.612+0000"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_assignees",
               "type":"cm:person",
               "value":[
                  "first",
                  "second"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"loopCounter",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":1
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_description",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"message... "
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"nrOfInstances",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":2
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"initiatorhome",
               "type":"d:noderef",
               "value":"workspace://SpacesStore/64f9f3c3-9227-425d-b336-bd255ab94c83"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_outcomePropertyName",
               "type":"d:qname",
               "value":"mswf:reviewOutcome"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"cm_name",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"Task"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"bpm_status",
               "type":"d:text",
               "value":"Not Yet Started"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"cancelled",
               "type":"d:boolean",
               "value":false
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"reviewAssignee",
               "type":"d:noderef",
               "value":"second"
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"mswf_requiredApprovePercent",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":100
            }
         },
         {
            "entry":{
               "name":"nrOfCompletedInstances",
               "type":"d:int",
               "value":0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In addition to everything else I'm interested in this part:

```
"entry":{
   "name":"bpm_assignees",
   "type":"cm:person",
   "value":[
      "first",
      "second"
   ]
}
```

Here is the list of the users who will participate in the business process (in this *specific instance*).

To get all this information, I need to know the ID of the process instance (`26205` in this case).

Can I determine this identifier in my `userdetails.ftl` template?

Comment: {"entry":{"dueAt":"2017-03-12T20:00:00.000+0000","‌​processDefinitionId"‌​:"contractsApproval:‌​116:26804","processI‌​d":"26938","name":"R‌​eview Task",...}
as you said that you can get your process ID from here.
and by this Id you are calling this url http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/workflow‌​/versions/1/processe‌​s/26938/variables
So.
It will be ok if you get id from url.

Comment: if you wanted to get Workflow instance Ids and task ids for particular user then it is also possible using rest apis.
freemarker api

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/API-FreeMarker-Workflow.html

or you can get it using java class also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow ID is indeed one of the variables available in your workflow, I suggest you add it to your form using the hidden form-control `hidden.ftl` and then, from you JS snippet, use dom to access that hidden input by ID/name and use it in your logic as you see fit !